# Display Custom Post Loop Under Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my custom template I have created a menu which is a row of 10 horizontal tabs. Each tab shows a date which is defined using an ACF datepicker field in the post.

I have also created a custom post type called 'Events' where I have added a custom field with the key 'grid_date'.

I want to display the Event post under the tab, when both dates match. For example in Tab 1 I add the date 01/09/2023. For any Events that also use this date, they will display under my Tab 1.

I have tried and my tabs display, but I cannot show any posts under the respective tabs with no console errors.
[image: ![Example of Tab array]

Code

```php
<div class="date-columns">
    <?php
    // Array of ACF field names for each heading's Date Picker value
    $acf_field_names = array(
        'date_field_1', 'date_field_2', 'date_field_3', 'date_field_4', 'date_field_5',
        'date_field_6', 'date_field_7', 'date_field_8', 'date_field_9', 'date_field_10'
    );

    // Loop through headings and display events posts under respective heading
    foreach ($acf_field_names as $acf_field_name) {
        $heading_date = get_field($acf_field_name); // Get the ACF Date Picker value

        // Initialize array for events posts matching the heading's date
        $events_for_heading = array();

        // Query events posts with matching ACF Date Picker value
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'events', // Update to the post type slug "events"
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'grid_date', // ACF Date Picker field in events posts
                    'value' => $heading_date,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );

        $events_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($events_query->have_posts()) {
            while ($events_query->have_posts()) {
                $events_query->the_post();
                $events_for_heading[] = get_the_ID(); // Store events post ID
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

        // Display the heading and its associated events posts
        echo '<div class="heading">';
        echo '<h3>' . $heading_date . '</h3>';

        foreach ($events_for_heading as $event_id) {
            $event_content = get_post_field('post_content', $event_id);
            $event_link = get_permalink($event_id);
            $event_detail = get_field('detail', $event_id);

            echo '<div class="post">';
            echo '<h4><a href="' . $event_link . '">' . get_the_title($event_id) . '</a></h4>';
            echo '<p>' . $event_content . '</p>';
            echo '<p class="detail"><strong>Detail:</strong> ' . $event_detail . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Styles

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.date-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.heading {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 5px;
}

.post {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.post h4 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.detail {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Can you be more explicit on the debug?

Comment: No errors in console. I also checked that the return format is the same for both ACF fields.

The result is I am seeing no posts under the respective tabs. Since when both value matches, I should be able to see the Events post display under the Tab.

Comment: Did you tried (while WP debug enabled) `error_log( print_r($events_query, true) );` to see if there is something wrong in each query?

Comment: Debug enabled and I couldn't find any query errors showing.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will troubleshoot and post my answer once I find it.

Comment: You should start by verifying whether your query returned any posts in the first place - with the while loop wrapped into `if ($events_query->have_posts())`, and then later on a foreach loop over an empty array, it will of course simply "fail silently" without any actual errors, and also not the desired output.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec ACF Datepicker always saves the value as Ymd (YYYYMMDD) in the database. I was not returning this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, as it turns out there was no error in my code.

As we can see referenced [link to ACF datepicker page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/) "Please note that the value is always saved as Ymd (YYYYMMDD) in the database"

My fields were set to return using the F,j Y format. I changed to YYYYMMDD and added a conversion statement for the front end `$formatted_date = date('F j, Y', strtotime($heading_date));`